# How can you make sure a C++ function can be called as

Tags: c++

How can you make sure a C++ function can be called as e.g. void foo(int, int) but not as any other type like void foo(long, long)?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a specific problem, or is this academic?

Answer (score 17):

Add a deleted template overload:

```
template <typename A, typename B> void foo(A, B) = delete;

void foo(int x, int y) {...}
```

It will be a better match (causing a error) for any argument types except `int, int`.

Comment: `foo(0LL, {});` calls the `int` version with a `long long` and an `int`.

Comment: You can do `template <typename A> void foo(A, A) = delete;` to catch that too.

Comment: @user975989 do you then have to do this for all permutations of 3 or more arguments?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Hmm good point, maybe you can make `foo` a template and specialize it for `<int, int>`? Seems kludgy, probably better to make a wrapper type that can only be constructed from `int` (in a similar way to this).